# Adding days to a Date object in JavaScript is not working properly

Tags: javascript, date

I have read several questions on stack overflow and all over the internet but somehow I am unable to get it right. I get a date from another function and the value is as below.

```js
var currentDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000");
console.log(currentDate); // this prints Wed Apr 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)

// want to add 45 days to my date
var offset = 45;
var xDate = new Date();
xDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + offset);
console.log(xDate);
```

The output I get is:

```
Mon Jul 12 2021 19:00:57 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

where as this should be some date in June.

Please can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the unit of `offset`? Is it hours, days, months, years, ...?

Comment: @WaisKamal I am trying to add 45 days

Comment: You are taking the current date and time (confusingly not called current but x in your code) and then changing only its day (which will change the month too if the number is larger than the number of days in the current month) based on the day of the other date plus 45, not taking into account year, month, hours, seconds and milliseconds. Try doing the operation on the same date and not a new one initialized to the current time and you'll see it working, or initialize the new date with the old date instead of nothing (which defaults to the current time).

Comment: @CherryDT thanks a ton your comment really helped me understand what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you are initializing a new date object using new Date(), the date object is initialized with the current date. When you increment the days using currentDate.getDate() + offset the day of the month is first set to that of currentDate and incremented by offset but the month from which it is incremented is the current month. Try this one.

```js
var currentDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000");
console.log(currentDate); // this prints Wed Apr 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)

// want to add 45 days to my date
var offset = 45;
var xDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000");
xDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + offset);
console.log(xDate);
```

Comment: I just changed the dates, and it does not give correct results: 

""" 
var currentDate = new Date("2022-02-28T15:30:27.588+0000"); var offset = 10; // 45 
// var xDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000"); var xDate = new Date("2022-02-28T15:30:27.588+0000"); xDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + offset); 
console.log("xDate: " + xDate); xDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - offset); console.log("xDate: " + xDate); 
"""

Answer (score 0):

1 day is equal to 86,400,000 milliseconds. You can multiply that value by 45 and add it to your date:

```js
var currentDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000");
console.log(currentDate);

// Add 45 days
var offset = 45;
var xDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + offset * 86400000);
console.log(xDate);
```

Comment: Or just `currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + offset)`. No real need to do multiplication.

Comment: I thought this won't work because it didn't for the OP that's why I went for the longer method. But yes, good point.

Comment: Doesn't work for OP because the code is manipulating `xDate` which is actually the current date, and modifying it by `currentDate`. So, it's a complete mish-mash. Unsurprisingly, the code works if it's correct.

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed.

Comment: I just changed the dates, and it does not give correct results: 

""" 
var currentDate = new Date("2022-02-28T15:30:27.588+0000"); var offset = 10; // 45 
// var xDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000"); 
var xDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + offset * 86400000); 
console.log("xDate: " + xDate); xDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - offset); 
console.log("xDate: " + xDate); 
"""

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
const addDays = (date, days) => {
  var ndt = new Date(date);
  ndt.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return ndt;
};

var date = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000");

console.log(date);
console.log(addDays(date, 45));
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but extending the prototype of native types is considered bad practice. There is even an ESLint rule to disallow such code: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extend-native

Comment: @Krisztián Balla Thank you very much for that info. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree Wais Kamal's answer is right. The below code is more succinct since you avoid time calculations

```
var currentDate = new Date("2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000");
var offset = 45;
var xDate = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + offset);
console.log(xDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the `moment` here. Link to [official docs](https://momentjs.com/docs). Don't forget to install moment package like so (assuming you are using npm)

```
npm i moment
```

```
  const myDate = "2021-04-27T15:30:27.588+0000";
  const updatedDate =  moment
          .utc(myDate)
          .add(45, 'days')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    
  console.log('updatedDate', updatedDate); // "2021-06-11"
```

Comment: I really like momentjs and if used correctly can save you from so much trouble. Using an entirely huge library(which momentjs actually is huge) just for one function is not good

Comment: Didn't downvote . However my  initial concern (see my comment) about moementjs remains